# How to provide language support on WPF XAML based UI

Tags: wpf, xaml, internationalization

I would like to provide language support on a WPF Application. To provide support for dynamic contents, I can make use of a language support file.

However, how should I go about doing this for Static texts, such as those found on XAML.

For example:

```
<TextBlock                 
            FontSize="20" 
            FontWeight="Bold"        
            TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Helvetica">                                
            Start Process
</TextBlock>
```

in the code above, the text "Start Process" is static, but how would I integrate different language support for that text.

Comment: Could you please help me to understand why tools like LocBaml will not work for here?

Comment: @Ujjwal: I am not familiar with LocBaml. I was actually looking for tools that can be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using genercal globalization and localization (language specific support) in WPF apps ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292205(v=vs.71).aspx

Using locale specific resource files in .net .... http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/Globalization_Localization_in_DotNet_CSharp07032006023510AM/Globalization_Localization_in_DotNet_CSharp.aspx

Using `x:Static` attribute in XAML to achieve binding of resource (.resx) texts ... http://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/wpf-add-localization-via-resx-files/

Comment: FYI:  first link no longer goes where it should.

Answer (score 1):

- LocBaml is a tool, microsodt has provided explicitly for fast language support for WPF.
- This tools adds Uids for every xaml tag and helps you to enlist those tags in CSV files (with some common properties).
- These CSV files then can be easily used to provide translations in different languages.
- There are certain disadvantages with this approach. Like, you will not get dynamic language switching with this. Sometimes, maintaining CSV files can be cubersome.
- Please refer [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653213/how-to-provide-language-support-on-wpf-xaml-based-ui)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Angel's advice is on target, especially the  last link for using `x:Static`. There is also a nice really article and code sample that uses this technique [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF)

What I like even better, currently, is a markup extension. A good example of one is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files)).

Localization is actually a fairly complicated affair even though it seems like you just want to say "Start Process" in Russian! I suggest you stick with the first Code Project article, and only that one, until it makes sense.

Than taking in the second article will be easier.

Last piece of advice I have is to not waste your time with LocBaml.

Cheers,
Berryl